# Does Kylo Ren know that Darth Vader reconciled with Luke?

Tags: star-wars, the-force-awakens, kylo-ren

In The Force Awakens, we see

> Kylo Ren trying to get a map to use to kill Luke Skywalker. We also see Kylo Ren praying to Darth Vader and otherwise trying to emulate Darth Vader in many ways.

But I recall Darth Vader removing his mask as he was dying so that Luke could be close to his father. Annakin ended life reconciled with Luke. Why does Kylo Ren not seem to know this?

[image]